# Play! framework with missing type Promise

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to get my first Scala + Play! application working, and I encounter this problem when trying to access my application (on port 9000) :

```
not found: type Promise
```

on this line:

```
val page: Promise[play.api.libs.ws.Response] = WS.url(googleApiUrl).get()
```

Those are my imports:

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.ws._
import play.api.libs.ws.Response
import play.api.http
import play.api.libs.concurrent._
import play.api.libs._
```

Am I missing something here ?

Those are logs on the console:

```
sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[not found: type Promise]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:322) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:322) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(PlayReloader.scala:322) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(PlayReloader.scala:319) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
```

Comment: What is you Play2 version ? Promise/Future API change a lot in latests releases

Comment: @JulienLafont I was using version 2.1 RC which was the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Play2.1 use Scala **Future** instead of play **Promise**.

Check the [migration guide](http://play2-docs-snapshot.herokuapp.com/render/Migration) for more informations, chapter "Play's Promise to become Scala's Future".

A simple exemple give something like that :

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.ws._

import play.api.libs.concurrent._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._

def myAction() = Action {
    Async {
        WS.url(googleApiUrl).get.map(response => Ok("what you want here"))
    }
}
```

You can check this [exemple](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/UylCl0mAa00) with a more complexe use of WS api.

Comment: Thanks, I was following this tutorial, but the real problem was that I missed one import: import scala.concurrent._

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with missing import:

```
import scala.concurrent._
```